# C,C++,Data type,Operator and expression

Tags: c++, c

```
void main()
{
    char c=255;
    char d=-1;
        if(c<0)
        cout<<"c is less than zero \n";
    else
        cout<<"c is greater than zero\n";
    if(d<0)
        cout<<"d is less than zero \n";
    else
        cout<<"d is greater than zero\n";
    if(c==d)
        cout<<"c and d are equal \n";
    else
        cout<<"c and d are not equal\n";

    cout<<d;
    getch();

}
```

Answer is 
c is less than 0
d is less than 0
c and d are equal

but if value of c is changed to 250,200 then c and d are not equal.What is ascii value of -1.Please explain the compilation process.how are c and d equal

Comment: Unless `char` is unsigned on you platform, or larger than a single octet, `char c=255` already puts you in an alternate universe. You're overflowing a `char` by assigning it an out-of-bounds `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

1. All the primitive datatypes are signed by default in C language.
2. char takes 1 byte (8 bits )of memory thus its ***range is -128 to 127***.
3. So, whenever it crosses its limits it starts reading in the loop form of its range.
4. Thus when you choose `c=128,129,130,.....,255` it will be equivalent to `-128,-127,-126,.....,-1` respectively because it starts counting from the backside to convert the number in the given char range.
5. Similarly, `c=-129,-130,.....` will be equivalent to `127,126,.... and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations simply store the bit-pattern, which for `255` is `0xFF` With a two's-complement interpretation, as a signed 8-bit integer, that is the bit-pattern of `-1`. But again this implementation defined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Signed char has a range of `-128 to 127`. When you assign 255 to a signed char, you are overflowing it, and it is as if you would assign -1, that's why it is equal

Answer (score 0):

signed char has a range Between **[-128,127]** -> **[10000000,01111111]**
unsigned char is [0,255]

changed c,d is unsigned char.

the ouput is :

c is greater than zero
d is greater than zero
c and d are equal。

"c and d are equal" is because both c and d is 255.